# Why can't I call .send on a publisher in a class from a second class and have it update the subscription in third class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reactive-programming, combine

I have this class in LRVDetails.swift

```
class LRVDetails {
    var heading = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>(K.LRV.Register)
    // other publishers
}
```

I have this assign in LRVViewController.swift

```
private var details = LRVDetails()
private var subs = Set<AnyCancellable>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    details
        .heading
        .assign(to: \.text!, on: heading)
        .store(in: &subs)
}
```

and in LRVCoordinator.swift I have

```
private var details = LRVDetails()

func UserDidPressButton() { // this is a delegate method from the VC
    details.heading.send("New Heading")
}
```

I thought that because LRVDetails is a class, it only stores a reference. so if I simply instantiate it in each file and then call send() on it, the publisher should update, and then emit the value to the LRVViewController subscription and update the heading.

But it does nothing. The subscriber never receives a value ( I checked with a .print() operator ). When i call lrvController?.details.send() -- without the private tag -- in the coordinator, it works fine.

Is this because the subscriber is stored in the 'subs' variable in LRVCoordinator, and thus it has to be updated with the subscriber in LRVViewController? That's my best bet.

If not, why doesn't this work?.

Thanks!

Edit:

If they are different instances, why does this code print two?

```
class myClass {
 var int = 1
}

let test1 = myClass()
let test2 = myClass()

test1.int = 2
print(test2.int)
// prints 2
```

Comment: You say `details = LRVDetails()` twice so those are two completely different unrelated instances. So each has its own `heading`. Subscribing to one does not magically subscribe to the other. Sending thru one does not magically send thru the other. “I thought that because LRVDetails is a class, it only stores a reference” It seems there is a misunderstanding of all the basic concepts — class, instance, and reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that because LRVDetails is a class, it only stores a reference. so if I simply instantiate it in each file and then call send() on it, the publisher should update

Your understanding is incorrect. You have created two different `LRVDetails` objects. (The syntax `LRVDetails()` creates a new object) One in the VC, and the other in the coordinator. You are correct that it stores *references* though, so it would work if you actually make the two `details` variable refer to the same `LRVDetails`.

But actually, you don't seem to need a `details` variable in the coordinator. Since the coordinator is the delegate of the VC, you could just pass the `LRVDetails` via the delegate method:

```
func UserDidPressButton(_ viewController: LRVViewController) {
    viewController.details.heading.send("New Heading")
}
```

Needless to say, you should also change the caller of `UserDidPressButton` to pass `self` as the parameter.

Comment: Wait wait wait then why does the code in my edit work? I can change the int of the first instance of myClass and print the second instance and it reflects the changes made to the first one.

Comment: How would I make the two details variables refer to the same object?

Comment: @Iskeraet The code in your edit does not print `2`. It prints `1`. See [here](https://repl.it/repls/IncomparableWaryCygwin#main.swift). If you can tell me the relationship between the coordinator and the VC, I can show you how you can make them point to the same object. Basically, you need a line such as `self.details = viewController.details` or `self.details = coordinator.details`.

Comment: @Iskeraet Maybe your lessons had `let test2 = test1` instead of `let test2 = myClass()`? That would indeed point them to the same object.